# Function pipelining with multiple parameters where one parameter is a generic list

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I am trying to perform functional pipelining but I cant get it to work for multiple function parameters, where one of the parameters is a generic list.

```
let function1(list:System.Collections.Generic.List<Person>, x:int) =
     // does stuff returns a new list but for demo purposes I will just return list passed in
     list

let function2(list:System.Collections.Generic.List<Person>, x:int) =
     // does stuff returns a new list but for demo purposes I will just return list passed in
     list
```

Then I try to create a pipelined function, but it does not work by doing the following:

```
myPipelinedFunction initialPersonList = function1 10 |> function2 300
```

The compiler complains with "the expression was expected to have type 'a * int but here has the type int"

Anything obvious that Im doing wrong?
Any help greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use pipelining, you need to write your functions so that they:

- Take multiple parameters rather than taking a tuple
- The list is the last parameter

For example:

```
let function1 (x:int) (list:System.Collections.Generic.List<Person>) =
   // does stuff returns a new list but for demo 
   // purposes I will just return list passed in
   list

let function2 (x:int) (list:System.Collections.Generic.List<Person>) =
   // does stuff returns a new list but for demo 
   // purposes I will just return list passed in
   list
```

As a side-note, I would not use .NET generic `List<T>` in pipelining, because it is a mutable data structure  - and so you can get confusing behavior. An immutable F# list or `seq<T>` is a better choice.

Comment: Thanks for the help Tomas, also changed to use seq<T> instead